# Changing the language of "to" in Shiny's dateRangeInput

Tags: r, shiny, locale

I'm very new to shiny or any dashboard related development for that matter. My question is kind of specific and only tackles how the data is displayed and does not talk about internal logic of the app.

I applied `language = "ru"` option inside dateRangeInput and it changed how the text within date selector is rendred but it did not change the "to" bettween the two datefields. I understand that it might sound like I'm nitpicking but these little details matter for what I'm trying to do. Screenshow to ilustrate the problem.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Калькулятор остатков"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeInput("dates","Временной диапазон",start = "2020-07-01", 
                                                  end = "2020-09-01", language = "ru"),
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The function `dataRangeInput` has an `seperator`- argument the default is `to`. You may change this to your desired word. `dateRangeInput("dates","Временной диапазон",start = "2020-07-01", end = "2020-09-01", language = "ru", separator = " XYZ ")`

Comment: @tamtam Please post as answer. `separator = " до "`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `dataRangeInput` has an `seperator`- argument, the default is `to`. You may change this to your desired word.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Калькулятор остатков"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeInput("dates",
                     "Временной диапазон",
                     start = "2020-07-01", 
                     end = "2020-09-01", 
                     language = "ru",
                     separator = " до "),
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Such a simple fix. Thanks!